# Copy/Paste Windows text to Raspberry Pi 4 shell stopped working after update on Raspbian Buster

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster

Earlier today I could `copy/paste` text from a windows text file into a cmd shell on brand new Raspberry Pi 4 running WiFi headless, accessed using VNCviewer.

After `apt update`, `apg full-upgrade` then `reboot`, this no longer works, like after the update, the Raspberry Pi 4 clipboard doesn't get the text whereas it did before the update.

I am using Windows 7 to VNCviewer (VNC-Viewer-5.3.2-Windows-64bit) to Raspberry Pi 4 that Raspbian Buster is running.

It still works fine for my Raspberry Pi 3. I need a clue.

Comment: The last VNC Viewer is : `VNC-Viewer-6.19.1115-Windows.exe`. You can take a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1081489/how-to-enable-text-copy-and-paste-for-vnc) maybe

Comment: Thanks @Ephemeral... got excited.. tried all of the suggestions in link (one at a time, etc.) but unfortunately none worked. Sad thing was that copy/paste worked this AM, before doing updates. Sigh.

Comment: Also on your desktop on the top bar you have the VNC icon , `right click` on it and go to `Options` and on the left you have in the menu `Users and Auths...` ensure you have the checkbox `Copy-paste text in both directions` checked for `Globals Auths`. (sorry i'm not english maybe your menu names differ). [The menu where you can find Options](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/images/vnc-server-cloud-dialog.png)

Comment: Thanks again @Ephemeral. I had already checked the VNC options, Copy/Paste was enabled. Tried VNC-Viewer-6.19.1115 = same problem.

Comment: Since the noted update, I had created and was using a new login, without sudo privs. Copy/Paste didn't work.
Logged in as root and Copy/Paste worked again, both directions.
Created new login with sudo priv and C/P worked both directions.
But, even when using root login, I cant C/P from Firefox in windows to FF on Rpi4 or vice-versa.
Using RPi-3B+ I can C/P from FF on RPi to FF on Windows but not the reverse.
Smelling like a permissions/privledges issue but I am clueless where to look.
About to give up... got a bigger issue to handle and it makes no sense either...

Comment: You shouldn't be using `full-upgrade` unless you have a specific reason to.  Which 95%+ of the time there is not.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in my comment above, I found that copy/paste text to/from windows app from/to RPI4 app works* when the user account is setup with sudo privileges (its not necessary to actually use sudo, just have the login in the sudo group).
Works when login as root too.
* One exception: C/P to/from Firefox in windows from/to Firefox on RPi4 doesnt work, either direction.
Moving on...

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.